# Citations missing with \bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Problem: only one citation (first one) is showing up when I use the `\bibliography` command.

What it looks like:

[image]

My main .tex file:

```
\bibliographystyle{siam}
\bibliography{bibtex}
```

My bibtex.bib file:

```
@article {3,
    author = {{Reynir Axelsson}},
    title = {{Tvinnfallagreining II}},
    journal = {Háskóli Íslands},
    publisher = {Háskóli Íslands},
    pages = {16, 26},
    year = {2005}
}

@article {2,
    author = {Runge C.},
    title = {Zur Theorie der eindeutigen analytischen Funktionen},
    journal = {Acta Math.},
    volume = {6},
    pages = {229},
    year = {1885}
}
```

Preamble.tex file:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[icelandic]{babel}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\selectlanguage{icelandic}
\usepackage[margin=2.3cm,b5paper,includehead]{geometry}
\usepackage[b5]{crop}
```

Document class:

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt,twoside,icelandic]{article}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. And, please confirm that you have both `\cite{2}` and `\cite{3}` instructions in the body of the document.

Comment: Document class added. I removed the \cite commands because it gave citation links which my professor asked me to remove. Updated with an image of that.

Comment: I had to use \nocite{*}, it works as intended now. Sorry, I'm a newbie.

Comment: For what it's worth, `author = {Runge C.}` is wrong. It should be either `author = {Runge, C.}` or `author = {C. Runge}`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as the OP has figured out a fix on his/her own in the meantime.